# fluidsynth on Mac, virtual port

Tags: macos, midi, fluidsynth

I installed fluidsynth from homebrew, and it works, but there is one issue.

When using an external MIDI keyboard, one needs to route the keyboard events to fluidsynth's virtual port. I am using MidiPipe (from http://www.subtlesoft.square7.net/MidiPipe.html) to do this.

Problem: fluidsynth assigns a random port number, so i have to check manually in MidiPipe to which port I can connect.
Is there a way to set the virtual port number fluidsyth is going to use explicitly?